# ubuntu 20.04 doesn't show any wifi option

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, broadcom

i've install ubuntu 21.04 and 20.04 on my pc but there is no wifi option in the top right br or in the settings.in the additional drivers broadcom 802.11 Linux sta wireless driver is showing but no wifi option is found [no wifi option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDisP.png)

Comment: Under Additional Drivers, did you try to install the Broadcom driver? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks... the issue was resolved. i guess i had some installation issue with uefi/legacy bios mode